# how to print the count of matched /unmatched patterns and print multiple patterns separated by line

Tags: grep, sort, search, uniq, patterns

how to print the count of  matched /unmatched patterns  and  print multiple patterns separated by line.

Input example (`test.log`):

```
This 23 line has eight 8888
This 11 line has three 3333
need 12 to separate eight and three 3333
eight 32 is greater than three 8888
three 13 is less than eight 3333
three 14 is printed more than eight 3333
```

Desired output :

```
8888:4
3333:2
5555:0
This 11 line has three 3333
need 12 to separate eight and three 3333
three 13 is less than eight 3333
three 14 is printed more than eight 3333
============================================
This 23 line has eight 8888
eight 32 is greater than three 8888
==========================================
```

what i have tried so far :

1. to get the number of lines: `egrep -o '8888|3333|5555' test.log | sort| uniq -c`

output:

```
4 3333
2 8888
```

but it's not printing `0 5555` to indicate zero occurrence of five in file 
test.log

desired output:

```
4 3333
2 8888
0 5555
```

2. `egrep '8888|3333' test.log | sort -V`

this sort output in alphabetic order and not according to the output i expect as shown below :

```
This 11 line has three 3333
need 12 to separate eight and three 3333
three 13 is less than eight 3333
three 14 is printed more than eight 3333
============================================
This 23 line has eight 8888
eight 32 is greater than three 8888
==========================================
```

Answer (score 2):

The program you're looking that can easily do what you want is called `awk`.  :-)

It can do programmed actions on matched RE patterns.

Untested, simplified, rote, example `awk` program that should work with your example input and specified patterns:

```
BEGIN {
    eights = 0;
    fives = 0;
    threes = 0;
}
/8888/ {
    eightln[eights] = $0;
    eights++;
}
/5555/ {
    fiveln[fives] = $0;
    fives++;
}
/3333/ {
    threeln[threes] = $0;
    threes++;
}
# ... and so on
END {
    printf("%d 8888\n", eights);
    printf("%d 5555\n", fives);
    printf("%d 3333\n", threes);
    for (i = 0; i < eights; i++) {
        print eightln[i];
    }
    print "=========="
    for (i = 0; i < fives; i++) {
        print fiveln[i];
    }
    print "=========="
    for (i = 0; i < threes; i++) {
        print threeln[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this wonderful program .millions of thanks . i know basics of awk but im a fresher kindly explain how these syntax work in awk 
/8888/ {
    eightln[eights] = $0;
    eights++;
}

for (i = 0; i < fives; i++) {
        print fiveln[i];
    }

Comment: I'm sure a simple Google search can lead you to many documents that describe AWK syntax in varying degrees of detail.  However I would recommend starting at the Wikipedia article:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK